# Airflow Sensor incomplete files list

Tags: python, airflow, etl, airflow-taskflow

I'm really curious to know, how airflow sensors work when a file is not completely copied/loaded to a target data storage. As an example: we have a filesystem, and sensor checks files within it. We are copying a large file to folder and it really takes some time. Will airflow sensor consume incomplete file or it will wait for the file to be fully loaded?

I'm really looking for an answer and haven't found anything similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see inside the code of FileSensor the answer.

The answer is that the operation system is responsible for the answer. in a test I made while downloading a big file "Mac" for example returned True while downloading the file

the idea is while you copy a big file give it a temporary extension and replace it to the real one after copy finished

```
 def poke(self, context: Context):
    hook = FSHook(self.fs_conn_id)
    basepath = hook.get_path()
    full_path = os.path.join(basepath, self.filepath)
    self.log.info("Poking for file %s", full_path)

    for path in glob(full_path, recursive=self.recursive):
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            mod_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(path)).strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
            self.log.info("Found File %s last modified: %s", str(path), mod_time)
            return True

        for _, _, files in os.walk(path):
            if len(files) > 0:
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: so, as i understood your answer, isfile returns True even if file is not completely copied, cause it is opened at the moment. So i need to implement adding, as an example '.' at the start of filename, and then replace it. Am i right?

Comment: right. Its a known trick. You can see an example when chrome is downloading file.

Answer (score 0):

Other solution, would be to implement a `NewFileSensor` class, similar to original `FileSensor`, which `poke()` method would test not only that file is present, but also that its size is constant during certain amount of time (10, 60secs)..
if a file is still being uploaded, then its size would also progressively change, and sensor will detect that. Perhaps checking update timestamp would also do..

This of course will not help in cases if the the upload was incomplett. Then your uploading application should control that somehow, and rename file from *.tmp to *.ext after upload, or create second empty flag-file like filename.done. which could be detected with standard `FileSensor`.